# How to adjust AVCaptureVideoPreview orientation to device current orientation?

Tags: swift, xcode, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapture

I am trying to adjust AVCaptureVideoPreview orientation to device current orientation and I tried someways which I found on Stackoverflow but it didn’t work. How can I adjust AVCaptureVideoPreview orientation to device current orientation?

Here are CameraManager.swift codes:

```
// MARK: Camera View Model
class CameraViewModel: NSObject,ObservableObject,AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate{
    @Published var session = AVCaptureSession()
    @Published var alert = false
    @Published var output = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
    @Published var preview : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    
    // MARK: Video Recorder Properties
    @Published var isRecording: Bool = false
    @Published var recordedURLs: [URL] = []
    @Published var previewURL: URL?
    @Published var showPreview: Bool = false
    
    // Top Progress Bar
    @Published var recordedDuration: CGFloat = 0
    // Timing
    @Published var maxDuration: CGFloat = 10
    
    func checkPermission(){
        
        switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
        case .authorized:
            setUp()
            return
        case .notDetermined:
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { (status) in
                
                if status{
                    self.setUp()
                }
            }
        case .denied:
            self.alert.toggle()
            return
        default:
            return
        }
    }
    
    func setUp(){
        
        do{
            self.session.beginConfiguration()
            let cameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .front)
            let videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: cameraDevice!)
            let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio)
            let audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice!)
            
            // MARK: Audio Input
            
            if self.session.canAddInput(videoInput) && self.session.canAddInput(audioInput){
                self.session.addInput(videoInput)
                self.session.addInput(audioInput)
            }
            
            if self.session.canAddOutput(self.output){
                self.session.addOutput(self.output)
            }
            
            self.session.commitConfiguration()
        }
        catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func startRecording(){
        // MARK: Temporary URL for recording Video
        let tempURL = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "\(Date()).mov"
        output.startRecording(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: tempURL), recordingDelegate: self)
        isRecording = true
    }
    
    func stopRecording(){
        output.stopRecording()
        isRecording = false
    }
    
    func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        
        // CREATED SUCCESSFULLY
        print(outputFileURL)
        self.recordedURLs.append(outputFileURL)
        if self.recordedURLs.count == 1{
            self.previewURL = outputFileURL
            return
        }
        
        // CONVERTING URLs TO ASSETS
        let assets = recordedURLs.compactMap { url -> AVURLAsset in
            return AVURLAsset(url: url)
        }
        
        self.previewURL = nil
        // MERGING VIDEOS
        mergeVideos(assets: assets) { exporter in
            exporter.exportAsynchronously {
                if exporter.status == .failed{
                    // HANDLE ERROR
                    print(exporter.error!)
                }
                else{
                    if let finalURL = exporter.outputURL{
                        print(finalURL)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.previewURL = finalURL
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func mergeVideos(assets: [AVURLAsset],completion: @escaping (_ exporter: AVAssetExportSession)->()){
        
        let compostion = AVMutableComposition()
        var lastTime: CMTime = .zero
        
        guard let videoTrack = compostion.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)) else{return}
        guard let audioTrack = compostion.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)) else{return}
        
        for asset in assets {
            // Linking Audio and Video
            do{
                try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: asset.duration), of: asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0], at: lastTime)
                // Safe Check if Video has Audio
                if !asset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).isEmpty{
                    try audioTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: asset.duration), of: asset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio)[0], at: lastTime)
                }
            }
            catch{
                // HANDLE ERROR
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            
            // Updating Last Time
            lastTime = CMTimeAdd(lastTime, asset.duration)
        }
        
        // MARK: Temp Output URL
        let tempURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + "Reel-\(Date()).mp4")
        
        // VIDEO IS ROTATED
        // BRINGING BACK TO ORIGNINAL TRANSFORM
        
        let layerInstructions = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)
        
        // MARK: Transform
        var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        transform = transform.rotated(by: .pi / 0.5)
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: 0)
        layerInstructions.setTransform(transform, at: .zero)
        
        let instructions = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
        instructions.timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: lastTime)
        instructions.layerInstructions = [layerInstructions]
        
        let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
        videoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: videoTrack.naturalSize.height, height: videoTrack.naturalSize.width)
        videoComposition.instructions = [instructions]
        videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
        
        guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: compostion, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else{return}
        exporter.outputFileType = .mp4
        exporter.outputURL = tempURL
        exporter.videoComposition = videoComposition
        completion(exporter)
    }
}
```

Here are my CameraPreview.swift codes:

```
   struct CameraPreview: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var cameraModel : CameraViewModel
    var size: CGSize
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) ->  UIView {
        
        let view = UIView()
        
        cameraModel.preview = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: cameraModel.session)
        cameraModel.preview.frame.size = size
        
        cameraModel.preview.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        
        view.layer.addSublayer(cameraModel.preview)
        
        cameraModel.session.startRunning()
    
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please check this question? It’s literally important. Thanks.